# Subtracting Numbers From A .txt File In Python

Tags: python

I want to be able to open the file i have, and append it so that if i want to subtract the number in the file by 2, it would print out the answer in the console by opening the file and reading it.

e.g. if the number in the file was 156, i would have to subtract it by 2, which is 154, this will then be displayed on the console!

this is all i have so far:

```py
a = file.open("xp.txt", "r")
a.read()
a.close()
```

How would i update it so that if i wanted to subtract it by an integer, that integer would be displayed on console?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the file just a list of numbers or is there more to it? off the top of my head I would suggest storing the read file in a variable and then processing from there - it is pretty easy - depending on the actual content of the file.

Comment: the file only has one number, it would either be 1, 2 or even 156, but it wont be separated by commas or have other numbers after.

Answer (score 1):

Use `readline` instead of `read` so that you won't get an error when the file for example contains another empty line. Then, call `strip` on the result to eliminate possible whitespace. Finally, use `int` to convert the string to a number. Now you can do all the math you want with it:

```py
with open("xp.txt", "r") as infile:
   value = infile.readline()

stripped = value.strip()
number = int(stripped)
newNumber = number - 2
print(newNumber)
```

Or shorter:

```py
with open("xp.txt", "r") as infile:
   print(int(infile.readline().strip()) - 2)
```

To write the number to the same file, convert the number back to a string:

```py
with open("xp.txt", "r") as infile:
   result = int(infile.readline().strip()) - 2

print(result)

with open("xp.txt" , "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(str(result))
```

Comment: thank you, i understand now!

Comment: is there any possible way that this new integer after getting subtracted would also be written to the file?

Comment: You might want to read "[Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)" in the tutorial.

Comment: @Exotic of course, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file just contained that single value and nothing else, you could accomplish this using the following

```
with open('xp.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    value = int(a.read())
    value -= 2
    print(f'New value is {value}')

with open('xp.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write(str(value))
```

Basically you open the file for reading, read the value into an integer, modify the value and display it, then re-open the file for writing to write the value back out.

Comment: great, made sense. thanks!